# comparing 2 list of dictonary in fastest way for performance

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I have two lists containing 500 dictonaries each:

```
list_1 = [{id:'1',...}, {id:'2',...}]
list_2 = [{id:'1',...}, {id:'2',...}]
```

> I need to compare both lists on the id basis. (id's are same, one is greater than another).

What is the most efficient way to compare and return the difference?

Could we also use `yield` to the function that does the comparison to return us the results one by one?

Comment: What kind of comparison? Desired output?

Comment: suppose id's are same then some flag like ID_EQUAL and first id is greater than second then ID1_MISSED and if second id is greater then ID2_MISSED. So basically, I need to do some processing on that basis

Comment: @KartikThakurela Provide two example lists (minimal) and their desired output. As the questions stands right now, there is too much room for interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list_1 = [{'unique_id':'001', 'key1':'AAA', 'key2':'BBB', 'key3':'EEE'}, 
              {'unique_id':'002', 'key1':'AAA', 'key2':'CCC', 'key3':'FFF'}]
>>> list_2 = [{'unique_id':'001', 'key1':'AAA', 'key2':'DDD', 'key3':'EEE'},
              {'unique_id':'002', 'key1':'AAA', 'key2':'CCC', 'key3':'FFF'}]
>>> pairs = zip(list_1, list_2)
>>> any(x != y for x, y in pairs)
True
```

Or to get the differing pairs:

```
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in pairs if x != y]
```

You can even get the keys which don't match for each pair:

```
>>> [[k for k in x if x[k] != y[k]] for x, y in pairs if x != y]
```

Possibly together with the associated values:

```
>>> [[(k, x[k], y[k]) for k in x if x[k] != y[k]] for x, y in pairs if x != y]
```